# Javascript : how to slice an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, I have an array of objects like this:

```
    for(var i=0; i<travelcard_table.length;i++){
        var table_row = travelcard_table.eq(i);
        var ii = 0;
        passenger_info[i] = {};
        table_row.find("td").each(function() {
                passenger_info[i][table_keys[ii]] = $(this).text();
                ii++;
        });
    }

passenger_info[0]['First name'] = "John"; etc..
passenger_info[1]['First name'] = "Chuck"; etc..
```

Im trying to split this to smaller arrays of objects every 10 entries, so Its something like this:

```
var size = 10;
for (var i=0; i<passenger_count; i+=size) {
    var smallarray = passenger_info.slice(i,i+size); << "Error: Slice is not a function"
    console.log(smallarray);
    // do something with smallarray
}
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What's `passenger_info` ?

Comment: Is the array called `passenger_details` or `passenger_info`? Sounds like `passenger_info` isn't an array.

Comment: Can you give a reproducable code, including the declaration of passenger_info ?

Comment: Sorry made a mistake here, updated

Comment: Is the error message exactly as the browser throws it? Then you're calling `.Slice()` (with a capital 'S') instead of `.slice()`

Comment: No, its the correct case, thing is, its working for simple array, but not for an array of objects

Comment: See my answer below for array of objects and arrays

Comment: Include a correct sample input

Comment: Include the declaration of `passenger_info`, ensure you declare it as `var passenger_info = []` and not as a `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var passenger_info = [[], []];

passenger_info[0]['First name'] = "John";
passenger_info[1]['First name'] = "Chuck"; 
var sliced = passenger_info.slice(0,1);
alert(sliced[0]['First name']);
```

This alerts 'John', because passenger_info is an Array of Array objects and you are attaching properties to the array object and not to its items.

for an array of objects it should be:

```
var passenger_info = [ {} , {}];

passenger_info[0].firstname = "John";
passenger_info[1].firstname = "Chuck"; 
var sliced = passenger_info.slice(0,1);
alert(sliced[0].firstname);
```

Comment: .slice doesnt work. I`ve updated the question, so maybe you`ll have a better understanding on how this goes.

Comment: what is the declaration of passenger_info before you do passenger_info[i] = {};, is it var passenger_info = [{}, {}] etc, there needs to be an element at i for it to be assigned to {}

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was {}. Changed it to [], and now everythings clear!

Comment: doing `passenger_info[0]['First name']` where `passenger_info[0]` is an Array, will only add a property called `First name` to the array, as it would do with an Object. Using an array of array here is useless since you don't use the array power. Also doing `object.firstname` and `object["firstname"]` is the same.

Comment: Yes u can use the index syntax to access object attributes, but in this case his array contains only objects so its unnecessary todo so.

Comment: @BhavO why use an array if you don't access element/properties by int index, you can't rely on `.length` as the array contains no element (only some properties). Using a raw object would have the same behavior.

Comment: Correct, added extra detail

Answer (score 0):

like this you can workout

```
for (var i=0; i<passenger_info.length; i+=10) {  
var smallArray = [];
    for(var j=0;j<10 && i+j < passenger_info.length;j++) {
        smallArray.push(passenger_info[i+j]);
    }
    console.log(smallArray);
}
```

for using slice you can do like this

```
for (var i=0; i<passenger_info.length; i+=10) {  
    var smallArray = [],ls;
        for(var j=0;j<10 && i+j < passenger_info.length;j++) {
            ls = i+j;
        }
        smallArray  = passenger_info.slice(i,ls+1); 
console.log(smallArray);
    }
```

Comment: This would work, however I was hoping for a more elegant solution. If no better solutions come up, I`ll accept your answer.